# Ruby/Sinatra is not passing variable from module file

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to print a name on the web page using modules etc, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass variables from the modules file.

main.rb

```
require 'sinatra' # includes gem to process web pages
set :bind, '0.0.0.0' # sets default url address to localhost

require_relative('modules')
include Display_name

get "/" do  
    Display_name.disname()
    erb :home
end
```

modules.rb

```
module Display_name

    def disname()
        @myname = "Bob"
    end
end
```

views/home.erb

```
<h1> Hello <%= @myname %> </h1>
```

Output should be Hello bob, but i'm just getting Hello.

Comment: I don't know anything about sinatra, but shouldn't you call `Display_name#disname` method anywhere explicitly to set this variable?

Comment: I don't think so, ````Display_name```` is the module name and ````disname```` is the method name

Answer (score 0):

When you included the module you made all its methods available to the router instance. So just call `disname` without an explicit receiver (a module) so that it would be dispatched to the router itself and it should work:

```rb
# ...

get "/" do  
  disname
  erb :home
end
```

(side note: `Display_name` looks lie an alien that came from OCaml world; Ruby convention for naming classes/modules is camel-case - `DisplayName`)